# Perl regular expressions compare text form of HTML

Tags: regex, perl

I am very new in Perl.

Previously two texts are compared this way:

```
        if($arr1[$k1-1] eq $arr2[$k2-1])
```

Now, I am looking for a Perl regex solution to compare two strings with each other in the form that it

- ignores case sensitivity
- All punctuation symbols are ignored
- All HTML tags such as `<B>`, `<BR />`, `<img src="aaaa.png" />`, `</B>` are ignored

I also need the number of words that are different between two texts (regardless of aforementioned cases)

Is there any solution for that in Perl?

Comment: The mention of HTML tags makes me think you need a parser vs. regex, what are the actual strings you want to compare?

Comment: I also like to use anything else. But we are forced to use regex. This is what question requires use. While there is no example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look on `Text::WordDiff` or `String::Diff` module (maybe `Text::Diff` is enough too).

Only by coding , I guess it's impossible to make in one single step.

without modules I should make the following steps:

First remove all html tags and punctuation (replace them with nothing or one space, depending on what you want, they are word separater or not) and after that you can compare them or count the differences.

1: remove html tags and punctuations:

```
$string =~ s/<[^>]+?>|[[:punct:] ]/ /igm; #replace with space in this case
```

after that remove multiple white spaces - not need if you use `/x` -  `($string =~ s/\s+/ /igm;)` , and compare them with eq or regex (`$string1 =~ //is;`), using the /x modifier ( /x = Extended with whitespace and comments; and depends on regex motor which you use) .

after that you need a function to eliminate words present on both texts (I guess multiple presence is ignored too) and get the count of remaining array.

code examples you can find [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=660854)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
#subroutine to clean html tags, pontuation and spaces > 2
sub clean {
my ($string) = @_;
$string =~ s/(<.+?>|[^\w\s])//ig;
$string =~ s/[\s]{2,}//ig;
return $string;
}

#clean the strings
my $str1 = clean('<B>, <BR />, <img src="aaaa.png" />, </B> test 123');
my $str2 = clean('<B>,  test 123 <BR />, <im g src="aaaa.png" />, </B>');


#compare two strings
if($str1 eq $str2){
print "equal"
}else{
print "not equal";
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/vvtVAs)